# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dest

Tags: c#, .net, zip, streamwriter

I have a small app that writes some text data to zipped text file. It works fine for the first archive, but after some time I get the following Unhandled exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dest
```

I've added `&& line.Lenght >0` because I thought that it might be the problem, but nothing changed.
I get 1 full archive in 3 hours and sometimes half of the second one, which is smaller, I suppose it is not finished, but is written to disk with .tmp extension. I can rename it to zip and open/unpack/read data.
If I change "counter" to a smaller period e.g. 10 minutes, it writes a bunch of archives like everything is fine. Enough to make me think the bug is gone.
So probably this error ecounters after some time aprox 4-5 hours.
How to fix this?

Stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dest
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity (System.Int32 value)
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity (System.Int32 value)
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count)
  at SharpCompress.IO.NonDisposingStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count)
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntryStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write (System.Char[] buffer, System.Int32 index, System.Int32 count)
  at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine (System.String value)
  at Program.DataWriter ()
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) 
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart ()
```

Here is the code:

```
static ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(DataWriter);
    thread.Start();
}

static void DataWriter()
{
    while (true)
    {
        string start = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
        DateTime counter = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);

        using (var archive = ZipFile.Open(HistoryPath + "history-" + start + ".tmp", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry data = archive.CreateEntry("data-" + start + ".txt");
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(data.Open()))
            {
                while (DateTime.Now < counter)
                {
                    if (queue.TryDequeue(out string line))
                    {
                        if (line != null && line.Length > 0)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }
        }

        File.Move(HistoryPath + "history-" + start + ".tmp", HistoryPath + "history-" + start + "_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".zip");
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI `if (line != null && line.Length > 0)` -> `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))`

Comment: So.... What is it you are actually trying to do, as this is likely the wrong (or suspect) approach

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm collecting string lines from different threads. I want them to be written inside of zip file line by line as they were added to queue. I want to split this for n hours period archives.

Comment: @TheGeneral I know this code could be optimesed a bit, like move `counter` and `start` otside the loop. I've tried to inspect what causes the error.

Comment: hmm.. it is interesting, because this exception is raising from the memory stream there... I don't think your code sample really causes the exception.. it does seem to relate to the stream itself being dropped.  Possibly stream handling of `ZipArchiveEntry`.. here's a similarly raised issue on a seperate product [github bug board](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/issues/563), but not too much help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing ZIP library solved my problem. I've changed Microsoft System.IO.Compression to [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib). The code is almost the same. Everything works as it should now. Seems there is an error in microsofts library.